# How to use a foreach loop to echo first name, last name, and email address objects in an array in PHP and along with HTML

Tags: php, arrays, class, object, foreach

I am new to PHP and have been struggling with echoing out a first name, last name, and email address as objects inside of a foreach loop. I have used a Profile.php class to define those and the get and set methods, and then I have a User.php class to set up a Username and Profile object and its get and set methods. I don't use the username object at all for my answer, according to people I have tried getting help from. I believe that the problem is within the foreach loop in index.php, but I have worked for hours and cannot wrap my head around it yet. 
[Here is the UML for the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5KEf.png)

[Here is what the program should ouput.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztVzq.png)

And here is the code itself:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php

        require_once('User.php');
        require_once('Profile.php');

        $professors = array("Andrew Besmer", "Gerry Derksen");

        $andrewUser = new User();
        $andrew = new Profile();

        $andrewUser->setProfile($andrew);

        $andrew->setFirstName("Andrew");
        $andrew->setLastName("Besmer");
        $andrew->setEmailAddress("besmera@fakeemail.com");

        $gerryUser = new User();
        $gerry = new Profile();

        $gerryUser->setProfile($gerry);

        $gerry->setFirstName("Gerry");
        $gerry->setLastName("Derksen");
        $gerry->setEmailAddress("derkseng@fakeemail.com");

        foreach($professors as $profile) {
            echo "<h2>" . $profile . "</h2>";
            echo "<ul>";
                echo "<li><b>First:</b>" . $profile->getFirstName() . "</li>";
                echo "<li><b>Last:</b>" . $profile->getLastName() . "</li>";
                echo "<li><b>Email:</b>" . $profile->getEmailAddress() . "</li>";
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Profile.php:

```
<?php
class Profile { 
    protected $firstName = "";
    protected $lastName = "";
    protected $emailAddress = "";

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function getFirstName(){
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName($firstName){
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName() {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName($lastName) {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function getEmailAddress() {
        return $this->emailAddress;
    }

    public function setEmailAddress($emailAddress) {
        $this->emailAddress = $emailAddress;
    }
}
?>
```

User.php:

```
class User {

protected $username = "";
protected $professors = array();

public function __construct(){

}

public function getUsername(){
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername($username) {
    $this->username = $username;
}

public function getProfile(){
    return $this->profile;
}

public function setProfile($profile){
    $this->profile = $profile;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help and your time.

Comment: You are doing it all wrong. First, `$professors = array("Andrew Besmer", "Gerry Derksen");` is an array. And you're running loop on this right? Then how would you get Class functions on that in your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$professors = array("Andrew Besmer", "Gerry Derksen");
```

As you can see, this array contains `string` (the names of professers), not objects. Thus, in the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($professors as $profile)
```

You will get the strings, `"Andrew Besmer"`, and then `"Gerry Derksen"` as the value of `$profile` variable, which is not what we want.

To solve this, you can define the `$professors` array after creating the objects, just before the `foreach` loop as follows:

```
$professors  = array($andrewUser, $gerryUser);
```

Then in the `foreach` loop, you will get `User` objects, and through which you can access `Profile` object:

```
foreach ($professors as $user) {
    echo $user->profile->getEmailAddress();
}
```

Hope this will help you get started to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I realize now that the array issue was dumb on my part. I should have known :/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 $professors = array("Andrew Besmer", "Gerry Derksen");
```

try using

```
$professors[] = $andrewUser;
$professors[] = $gerryUser;
foreach ($professors as $professor) {
  echo "<h2>" . $professor->profile->getFirstName() . "</h2>";
  etc...
}
```